# Error using GPG encryption in Evolution

Tags: evolution, gnupg, openpgp

After I did fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 I had to setup GPG encryption with Evolution again and it is not working properly (prior to fresh install it worked fine on Ubuntu 15.04

After I select `Option` > `GPG encrypt` I am getting this error:

> Because "gpg: CEF41E5C: skipped: unusable public key gpg: [stdin]:
>   encryption failed: unusable public key ", you may need to select
>   different mail options.

How to fix this error? thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does `gpg -K` print?

Comment: @JensErat it prints this http://sprunge.us/FdaB

Comment: This tells your private key _should_ be available. Some days ago there was another post with similar problems, but not necessarily a duplicate (although chances are high): http://askubuntu.com/questions/690548/gpg-agent-enigmail-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: From GnuPG, and especially to Enigmail. `gpg -K` (or the long version `gpg --list-secret-keys`) prints the secret keys available in your key chain.

Comment: @JensErat see my answer, dont forget to vote up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

You have two keys, one is `pub` and other is `sub`

```
edward@computer:~$ gpg --edit-key CEF41E5C
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.18; Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

pub  4096R/CEF41E5C  created: 2015-07-27  expires: never       usage: SC  
                     trust: full          validity: unknown
sub  4096R/BB84D566  created: 2015-07-27  expired: 2015-08-26  usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). edward torvalds (encrypt the world) <ltorvalds024@gmail.com>
```

as you can see my  `pub` key is fine but `sub` key is expired
now select `sub` key

```
key 1
```

next

```
expire
```

then enter the time after which it should expire, I choose `0` which means never

```
save
```

Done! :-)